# Spark reduceByKey(arguments) in the type {type} is not applicable for the arguments {arguments}

Tags: java, apache-spark, reduce

I am getting following error, for reduce, fold and reduceByKey functions. I searched across the forums but no luck.

> The method reduceByKey(Function2) in the type
>   JavaPairRDD is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   Function2(){})

`termsRDD` is of type `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer>`

```
    termsRDD.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -376611514417758310L;

        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0+arg1;
        }

    });
```

It's a fairly simple code that sum up the values against the keys separately.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implemented wrong interface.

- `JavaPairRDD.reduceByKey` takes [`org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function2.html) which requires `call` method.
- It looks like you are trying to implement `scala.Function2`

Should be

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;

termsRDD.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer>(){
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) throws Exception {
        return arg0+arg1;
    }
});
```